# Comma between two function calls in one line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was working on a python project when I noticed the following bit of code:

```
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
```

I have never seen anything like this as I previously thought one could only put one function on one line. What does this mean? Is there a difference between doing this or placing the functions on different lines like below?

```
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is:

There is no difference for the results.

It's just a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in what you want to do with the values returned by the function calls.

Here's an example from a Python REPL session. First we define some functions:

```
In [1]: def foo():
   ...:     return 'FOO'
   ...: def bar():
   ...:     return 'BAR'
   ...:
```

Then we call them, separated by a comma. The functions execute and return values. The comma sort of acts as an operator that creates a tuple. It seems that the comma is not strictly considered an operator the way it is in other languages; rather, the comma is just a part of the [language syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) for assignment statements.

```
In [2]: foo(), bar()
Out[2]: ('FOO', 'BAR')
```

You could do the same thing more explicitly by typing the outer parentheses:

```
In [3]: (foo(), bar())
Out[3]: ('FOO', 'BAR')
```